How to push reverb event notifications out of private group?
I'm working on a project which users can create public or private groups. 
Now I want to push live post notifications using Laravel 11 Reverb events. 
The problem is that a user who is member of a private group might be somewhere else on the website.  In this situation I have no direct access to ID of that private group.
At this stage, I secured broadcast channel using group ID and this is a good approach while user is in the private group and it doesn't work when user is in other private group or somewhere else on the website. 
I tried few ways broadcast events for users who are not active in the group. For example, I secured broadcast channel with User ID and then in the controller I looped through group->members()->chunk() but this approach for a group with heavy number of members is not good:  
$this->group->members()->chunk(250, function ($users) use ($auth) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->pivot->member_id === $user->id) {
                broadcast(new GroupEvents(
                        $this->group,
                        $user,
                        $auth,
                        [
                          "refresh" => true,
                          "title" => "The {$this->group->name} group is being archived.",
                          "message" => "{$auth->full_name} has archived the {$this->group->name} group. All actions within this group are now disabled.",
                        ]
                ))->toOthers();
        }
    }
});

The second method is that I create a notification using $user->notify() and then in global layout on the front-end I use Inertia usePoll() to update user unread_notifications every 3 minutes.
IF user is in the private group then they will receive broadcasted notification right away and if user is not active in the group at that moment then they will be notified 3 minutes later or any other time that they are active on the website. Even for this method I still need to loop through group members to prepare notifications for them.I’d appreciate any advice on improving this solution or suggestions for a better approach to handle notifications effectively for large groups.
Thank you in advance!
// channel.php
Broadcast::channel('group.events.{id}', function (User $user, $id) {
    $group = Group::findOrNew($id);
    return $user->address && $group->members()
        ->wherePivot('member_id', $user->id)
        ->exists();
});


//GroupEventsJob.php
public array $inputs;
    public Group $group;
    public User $user;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     */
    public function __construct($group, $user, array $data)
    {
        $this->inputs = $data;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->group = $group;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
        $inputs = new Fluent($this->inputs);

        broadcast(new GroupEvents(
            $this->group,
            $this->user,
            [
                "refresh" => $inputs->refresh,
                "title" => $inputs->title,
                "message" => $inputs->message,
            ]
        ))->toOthers();

        $this->group->members()->chunk(250, function ($users) use ($inputs) {
            foreach ($users as $user) {
                if ($user->username !== $this->user->username) {
                    $user->notify(new \App\Notifications\GroupEvents([
                        "title" => $inputs->title,
                        "message" => $inputs->message,
                        "url" => null,
                        "group_id" => $this->group->uid
                    ]));

                    if ($user->last_activity === null) {
                        $user->notifications()
                            ->whereNull('popped_at')
                            ->update(['popped_at' => now()]);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}


// GroupController.php
public function archive(string $group)
    {
        if (!$this->group->is_archived) {
            $auth = auth()->user();
            $this->group->is_archived = now();
            $this->group->join_code = null;
            $this->group->save();

            dispatch(new GroupEventsJob(
                $this->group,
                $auth,
                [
                    "refresh" => true,
                    "title" => "The {$this->group->name} group is being archived.",
                    "message" => "{$auth->full_name} has archived the {$this->group->name} group. All actions within this group are now disabled.",
                ]
            ));

            inertia()->clearHistory();

            return back()
                ->with('message', [
                    "type" => "success",
                    "content" => "The group has been successfully archived."
                ]);
        }
}

